# Extracting start and end indices of a token using spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I am looking at lots of sentences and looking to extract the start and end indices of a word in a given sentence.

For example, the input is as follows:

"This is a sentence written in English by a native English speaker."

And What I want is the span of the word 'English' which in this case is : (30,37) and (50, 57).

Note: I was pointed to this answer ([Get position of word in sentence with spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049612/get-position-of-word-in-sentence-with-spacy))

But this answer doesn't solve my problem. It can help me in getting the start character of the token but not the end index.

All help appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A very noob question for python word/phrase matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72172399/a-very-noob-question-for-python-word-phrase-matching)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with re in pure python:

```
s="This is a sentence written in english by a native English speaker."

import re
[(i.start(), i.end()) for i in re.finditer('ENGLISH', s.upper())]

#output
[(30, 37), (50, 57)]
```

You can do in spacy as well:

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc=nlp("This is a sentence written in english by a native English speaker.")
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.text.upper()=='ENGLISH':
      print(ent.start_char,ent.end_char)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea from the answer you link you could do something like this

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
s = nlp("This is a sentence written in english by a native English speaker")
boundaries = []
for idx, i in enumerate(s[:-1]):
    if i.text.lower() == "english":
        boundaries.append((i.idx, s[idx+1].idx-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this using SpaCy, which do not need any check for the last token (unlike @giovanni's solution):

```
def get_char_span(input_txt):

  doc = nlp(input_txt)

  for i, token in enumerate(doc):
    start_i = token.idx
    end_i = start_i + len(token.text)

    # token span and the token
    print(i, token)
    # character span
    print((start_i, end_i))
    # veryfying it in the original input_text
    print(input_txt[start_i:end_i])

inp = "My name is X, what's your name?"
get_char_span(inp)
```